# How to slowly pass ember component a repeating list of data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Hey so im trying to pass a component different data in a rotation, so say I have a few objects in my controller class

```
a: {
   name: "a",
   number: 6
}
b: {
   name: "b",
   number: 15
}
```

And I want to pass them to a component in the template file:

```
{{my-component data=a}}
```

But I want to pass my-component the data in a loop of the data 'a' being displayed for 4 seconds, then the data of 'b' being displayed for 4 seconds, then just continuously repeating this until the page has been changed. A few thoughts on how I can do this, and which I have tried, but hasn't worked.

Using Ember.run.later and attempting to call the function (I get the error that 'self.function()' is not a function (Note this is in the actions section of the controller, it starts rotating when you click a button.):

```
 function: function(){
   var self = this;
   return self.get('test');
   Ember.run.later((function() {
     if(self.get('test'))
        self.set('test', false);
     else
        self.set('test', true);
     self.function();  // <-- Error is here
   }), 4000);
 }
```

And then using an if statement in the template:

```
   {{#if test}}
      {{my-component data=a}}
   {{else}}
      {{my-component data=b}}
   {{/if}}
```

So it runs this for the first time, but it never actually keeps rotating through these two data items. 
Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about just pass in an array directly in the component and let the component cycle through the array. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vilode/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the data you are passing to the component.

```
{{my-component data=selectedObject}}
```

In your controller:

```
selectedObject: {},
count: 0,
allObjects: [
  {
      name: "a",
      number: 6
  },
  {
      name: "b",
      number: 6
  }
],
rotateObject: function() {
    this.set('selectedObject', this.get('allObjects')[count]);
    this.set('count', this.get('count')+1);
    Ember.run.later(function(){
        this.rotateObject();
    },4000);
}
```

This way, every 4 seconds the selectedObject will change and the component will be updated with the new data.
I changed the objects to be in an array.I'm sure you can figure out a way for that.